# Internet Explorer growing div when hovering anchor with inline-block

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I used `inline-block` to arrange several anchors as tabs in a tab strip that scrolls horizontally upon overflow rather than wrapping the tabs to multiple lines.

This works great in Chrome and FF on Windows, and on Chrome/Safari on iPad, but is really funky on IE 9.

The problem on IE 9 is that when I hover the anchor tags the psuedo selector that changes the color and BG color of the element is causing the parent div to increase it's height. I assume this is an IE 9 bug, but I have been unable to verify.

I have found a hack fix that involves wrapping the parent element in a block element with `overflow:hidden` and a specific `height`, but I want to to avoid using a specific height if possible.

**Questions**:

1. What is the generic fix that doesn't involve an IE hack or specific width?
2. Why does this occur only when the `:hover` psuedo class is used?
3. Is there a better practice for doing tabs the way I want to do them (scroll if exceed width; do not wrap)?

Problem fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oyzpxr6m
Hack fix fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oyzpxr6m/1/

Example code:

```css
.tabs {
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: auto;
}
.tabs a {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #fff;
}
.tabs a:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
  <div class='tabs'>
    <a href='tab'>tab name goes here</a>
    <a href='tab'>tab name goes here</a>
    <a href='tab'>tab name goes here</a>
    <a href='tab'>tab name goes here</a>
    <a href='tab'>tab name goes here</a>
    <a href='tab'>tab name goes here</a>
    <a href='tab'>tab name goes here</a>
    <a href='tab'>tab name goes here</a>
    <a href='tab'>tab name goes here</a>
    <a href='tab'>tab name goes here</a>
    <a href='tab'>tab name goes here</a>
    <a href='tab'>tab name goes here</a>
    <a href='tab'>tab name goes here</a>
    <a href='tab'>tab name goes here</a>
    <a href='tab'>tab name goes here</a>
    <a href='tab'>tab name goes here</a>
    <a href='tab'>tab name goes here</a>
    <a href='tab'>tab name goes here</a>
    <a href='tab'>tab name goes here</a>
    <a href='tab'>tab name goes here</a>
    <a href='tab'>tab name goes here</a>
    <a href='tab'>tab name goes here</a>
    <a href='tab'>tab name goes here</a>
    <a href='tab'>tab name goes here</a>
    <a href='tab'>tab name goes here</a>
    <a href='tab'>tab name goes here</a>
    <a href='tab'>tab name goes here</a>
    <a href='tab'>tab name goes here</a>
</div>

<h3>some content goes here</h3>
```

Comment: Hmm, just realized I can use `display:inline` instead, duh, but still wondering why this 'bug' occurs only in IE

Comment: @nothingisnecessary Awesome bug! I am an engineer on the IE team, and will gladly look into this for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excellent bug. This appears to only affect Internet Explorer 9, being resolved in versions 10 and up. While I'm not entirely aware of what is causing the problem, the issue certainly is with the expanding height of the `.tabs` container on each pass over one of its nested `.tab` elements.

A straight-forward fix that will resolve the issue across all browsers is simply to apply a `max-height` to the containing element. The specific approach I took is below:

```css
.tabs {
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm kinda glad it is a bug because no other explanation made sense and I was beginning to doubt my sanity. IE8 is not affected (didn't try 7 since no `inline-block` support and we stopped supporting it with XP end of life). Confirmed that your fix works with IE 8, 9,  10, 11, Chrome(latest on Win), FF(latest on Win), and Chrome & Safari on iPad. (Much better than my solution of using `display:inline` and `line-height` to make up for padding, shifting colors around, etc.)